# Augmentation while overfitting to trainset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, data-augmentation, overfitting-underfitting

I'm working on audio classification task. I have dataset with around 20k samples and I'm using some model, let's call it x from torchvision models hub(trained on Imagenet)

I'm pretty fast (around 10-15) epochs reaching high performance on my metrics for the training set and the loss starting to saturate.

When the train loss stop decreasing the validation metrics also stop improving.

- Should I apply augmentation on this scenario?
  Even with augmentation the training stats reaching saturation pretty fast. Thus it mean I should build my own small nn network ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the performances of the validation set compared to training set (without augmentation and assuming no data shifting)?

Comment: @ValentinGoldité they keep improving till the training loss stop decreasing , and then the validation metrics stop improving

Comment: So now your goal it to fit the training set more deeply. I suggest you increase the size of the architecture if you can. Later you would want to regularize your model and apply augmentation.